# Convergence of a dominated series

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be symmetric random variables with $|X_n| \leq |Y_n|$ such that the pairs $(X_n, Y_n)$ are independent. Suppose that $\sum_{n} Y_n$ converges almost surely. How do I show that $\sum_n X_n$ converges almost surely?

Comment: Here, does "converges" mean "converges almost surely"?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

This method might be overkill, as it appeals to a high-power theorem.

Let $a\wedge b$ denote $\max(a,b)$. From the Kolmogorov Three series theorem, $\sum Y_n$ converges if and only if there exists a constant $A$ where
$$
\sum P(|Y_n|>A)<\infty \qquad \sum E(Y_n1_{|Y_n\le A|})\,\,\text{  converges, and}\qquad\sum var(Y_n1_{|Y_n|\le A})<\infty
$$
You can then use the fact that these conditions hold for $Y_n$ to prove that they hold for $X_n$, and deduce that $\sum X_n$ converges a.s.

Comment: The r.v. $(X_n)$ need to be independent to apply Kolmogorov's Three series lemma no?

Comment: Yes, which they are. You said the pairs (Xn,Yn) form an  independent sequence, which implies that Xn is an independent sequence